# Is Collection(Of T) a 0-based array or 1-based array?

Tags: vb.net

If it's 0-based, how can we add a placeholder to make it 1-based? Thank you.

Comment: You better have a *really* good reason for even considering this. Switching to a 1-based container in a world of 0-based containers is guaranteed to confuse programmers who have to maintain or work with this code in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is 0-based. A return question might be: *why* do you want to make it 1-based?

With Extension Methods you could (if you wanted) do:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function GetOneBased(Of T)(ByVal list As IList(Of T), ByVal index As Integer) As T
   Return list(index-1)
End Function

<Extension()>
Public Sub SetOneBased(Of T)(ByVal list As IList(Of T), ByVal index As Integer, ByVal value As T)
   list(index-1) = value
End Sub
```

then use (from almost any collection):

```
Dim foo = data.GetOneBased(1)
data.SetOneBased(1, bar)
```

Comment: Because the old code used the collection which is 1-based, so now i'm simplifying it, but if it's 0-based, there will be a huge number of statements must be modified. So...

Answer (score 2):

it is 0 based. if you want to make it 1 based why not make a read method which accepts an index removes one and then use that and return the value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Insert( int index, T item )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132411.aspx) to insert an item at position 0, but I think you'd be better off doing index arithmetic and referencing as a 0-based collection.  This is what most programmers coming after you will expect.  @Robert's extension method idea has some value, but I think will end up confusing the eventual maintainers of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to make it 1-based?  Arrays in VB.Net used 0-based indexes as well.